# ¿Cómo encontrar un Triplete Pitagórico que cumpla que a+b+c=1000?

Tags: javascript

Tengo que hacer un ejercicio en el que me piden que escriba una función en JavaScript que, dados tres valores a, b y c, compruebe que forman un triplete pitagórico. 
Y después Escriba un programa en JavaScript que, usando esta función, encuentre un triplete pitagórico que cumpla que a+b+c=1000.*/

yo he hecho la función tal que así:

```
function triplePitagorico(n1,n2,n3){
  if(n1<n2 && n2<n3){
     let one = Math.pow (n1,2);
     let two = Math.pow (n2,2);
     let three = Math.pow (n3,2);
     if(one+two == three){
         console.log("Es un triple pitagórico");
     }else{
         console.log("No es un triple pitagórico, vuelve a intentarlo");
     }
  }else{
      console.log ("Utilaza otros números tal que a < b < c ");
  }
}
triplePitagorico(a,b,c);
```

Pero ahora no se como realizar la segunda parte he encontrado éste código pero no se como añadir la función al código, no me sale:

```
function mil (sum) {
    for (let a = 0; a <= sum; a++) {
        for (let b = 0; b <= sum; b++) {
            for (let c = 0; c <= sum; c++) {
                if (a < b 
                    && b < c 
                    && a + b + c == sum 
                    && (c * c == a * a + b * b)) {
                        console.log("a es " + a + ", b es " + b + ", c es "+ c + " y cumplen que a + b + c es igual a 1000");
                        return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
let num = 1000;
milla = mil(num);
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Casi lo tienes. Cambia la funcion `triplePitagorico` para que, en lugar de sacar mensajes por consola, devuelva TRUE o FALSE.  Luego, en el segundo caso, cambias el `if` por una llamada a la funcion. Como esta te va a devolver true o false, solo deberas escribir el mensaje cuando te devuelva true Y la suma sea `sum`. No te hace falta comprobar que sean a<b<c porque lo compruebas en la funcion.

Comment: Wow, es impresionante, ambas funciones funcionan perfectamente! (cosa que se vee poco +1 por eso).

Comment: @Jakala Podrías expandirlo añadiéndolo como respuesta ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hola lo he modificado así, pero no se si está bien, me parece que no sale:

```
let num = 1000;
let milla = mil(num);

function mil (sum) {
    for (let a = 0; a <= sum; a++) {
        for (let b = 0; b <= sum; b++) {
            for (let c = 0; c <= sum; c++) {
                let terna = triplePitagorico(a,b,c);
                if (terna == true && a + b + c == sum){
                    console.log("a es " + a + ", b es " + b + ", c es "+ c + " y cumplen que a + b + c es igual a 1000");
                }else{ 
                    console.log ("No encontrado.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function triplePitagorico(n1,n2,n3){
    if(n1<n2 && n2<n3){
        let one = Math.pow (n1,2);
        let two = Math.pow (n2,2);
        let three = Math.pow (n3,2);
        if(one+two == three){
            return true;
        }else{ 
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        console.log ("Utiliza otros números tal que a < b < c ");
    }
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: No uses el espacio de respuestas para añadir más a tu pregunta, en vez de eso, edita tu pregunta. Este espacio es exclusivo para respuestas, si tu intención es responder la pregunta asegúrate de que cumpla con [answer]. Saludos

Comment: la función `triplePitagorico` tiene un problema, y es que no siempre devuelve un valor. solo haces return true o false en caso de la condicion de ser triplete, pero en caso de que los valores n1, n2 y n3 no cumplan la primera condicion, solo sale un mensaje. En la funcion `mil` haces bucles anidados empezando todos desde 0. Por lo que, al menos, la primera iteracion de `c` le estas pasando 0,0,0 a la funcion tripletePitagorico.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias ya lo he resuelto en la función mil he modificado los bucles: for (let a = 0; a <= sum; a++) {
           for (let b = a + 1; b <= sum; b++) {
               for (let c = b + 1; c <= sum; c++) .Muchas gracias.

Comment: Aunque la pregunta y respuesta sean viejas: tu comentario debería ser la verdadera respuesta, y lo que está aquí como respuesta, debe ser una edición a tu pregunta. No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te ha sido más útil.

Answer (score 0):

Yo cree el siguiente script:

```js
const alg = {
    a: 3,
    b: 4,
    c: 5,
    isValid() {
        return Math.pow(this.a, 2) + Math.pow(this.b, 2) == Math.pow(this.c, 2) && this.a + this.b + this.c == 1000
    },
    exec() {
        for (let a = 1; a < 1000; a++) {
            for (let b = 1; b < 1000; b++) {
                const c = 1000 - a - b
                this.a = a;
                this.b = b;
                this.c = c;
                if (this.isValid()) {
                    console.log("a=", a, "b=", b, "c=", c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
alg.exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola dejo aquí otra versión:

```js
// Tripe-Trigonometrico
function isValid(a,b,c){
    return(a < c) && (b < c);
}

function esTriplePitagorico(a,b,c){
    return (Math.pow(a,2) + Math.pow(b,2)) == Math.pow(c,2);
}

function encontrarTriplePitagoricoEn(limite){
    for(let a = 1 ; a <= limite; a++)
        for(let b = 1 ; b <= limite; b++){
            let c = limite - a - b;
            //Se comprueba si el estado actual de a y b sirven para continuar
            //En caso contrario se rompe la ejecucion del bucle
            if(!isValid(a,b,c)) break;
            //Se comprueba si es un triplePitagorico y se muestra por pantalla
            if(esTriplePitagorico(a,b,c))
                console.log("a:" + a,",b:" + b,",c:" + c );
        }
}
```

Espero que sea de utilidad.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

hice una pequeñas modificaciones para tu desafio, comentame si te sirve

```js
const isTriplete = (n1,n2,n3) => Math.pow(n1,2) + Math.pow(n2,2) ==  Math.pow(n3,2);

const sumaMil = (n1,n2,n3) => n1+n2+n3 == 1000;

let sum = 1000
    for (let a = 1; a <= sum; a++) {
        for (let b = 1; b <= sum; b++) {
            for (let c = 1; c <= sum; c++) {
                 if(sumaMil(a,b,c) && isTriplete(a,b,c)){
                     console.log(a,b,c, isTriplete(a,b,c) && sumaMil(a,b,c))
                 }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Una opción podría ser:

```js
const isTriple = (a, b, c) => Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2) === Math.pow(c, 2); // Triples Pitagórico

const findTripleTo = (n) => {
  for (let a = 1; a < n; a++) {
    for (let b = 1; b < n; b++) {
      for (let c = n; c > 0; c--) { // Ciclo de n a 1
        if (a + b + c === n && isTriple(a, b, c)) { // Si cumple las condiciones
          return [a, b, c];
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

findTripleTo(1000); // Se espera [200, 375, 425] que suma 1000 y es un triplete Pitagórico
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución:

```js
const isTriplete = ({a,b,c}) => {
  return (Math.pow(a,2) + Math.pow(b,2)) === Math.pow(c,2)
};


const findTripleteForSum = (sum) => {
  console.log('buscando para', sum);
  const start = performance.now()

  let solA = null;
  let solB = null;
  let solC = null;
  
  const SUM = sum;
  const halfSum = Math.ceil(SUM/2);

  let shouldBreakOuter = false;
  for(let i=1; i<=halfSum; i++) {
    if(shouldBreakOuter) {
      break;
    }
    for(let j=i; j<=(halfSum); j++) {
      const aPow2Bpow2 = Math.pow(i,2) + Math.pow(j,2);
      const myC = Math.round(Math.pow(aPow2Bpow2,0.5));
      if(isTriplete({a: i, b: j, c: myC}) && ((i+j+myC) === SUM)){
        shouldBreakOuter = true;
        solA = i;
        solB = j;
        solC = myC;
        break
      }
    }
  }
  if(solA === null) {
    console.log('no hay solución')
  } else {
    console.log('a', solA)
    console.log('b', solB)
    console.log('c', solC)
  }
    const duration = performance.now() - start;
  
  console.log('executed in', duration, 'milisecs');
}

findTripleteForSum(850);
findTripleteForSum(1000);
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente qué hace este código. Recuerda que [es.so] no es un repositorio de código. Lee [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Esta es mi propuesta de calculo para los tripletes pitagoricos:

```js
const isValid = (a, b, c) => a < b && b < c;
const esTriplete = (a, b, c) => isValid(a, b, c) && ((a ** 2) + (b ** 2)) === (c ** 2);

function encontrarTripletePorValor(valor)
{
    let it = 0;
    let res = false;
    const performanceBef = performance.now();

    outer: for(let a = 1; a <= (valor / 2); a++)
    {
        //b siempre comenzara una unidad por delante de a
        for(let b = a + 1; b <= (valor / 2); b++)
        {
            //podemos calcular directamente un valor c compatible con el triple 
            //teniendo a y b usando la hipotenusa
            const c = Math.hypot(a, b);

            //Comprobamos que sea realmente un triplete
            if(esTriplete(a, b, c))
                //Comprobamos que la suma de a, b y c sea igual al valor requerido
                if(a + b + c === valor)
                {
                    res = { a, b, c };
                    break outer;
                }

            it++;
        }

        it++;
    }

    const performanceAfter = performance.now();
    const totalTime = performanceAfter - performanceBef;

    console.log(`Ejecucion terminada en: ${totalTime} ms`);
    console.log(`Numero de iteraciones realizadas: ${it}`);

    return res;
}

console.log(encontrarTripletePorValor(1000));
```

La verdad es que pude observar o me percate luego con la respuesta del usuario `santiago` que era posible liberarnos de un `for` calculando `c` mediante la hipotenusa, asi que creditos para el, al parecer ambos llegamos a conclusiones parecidas.